# unable to create header and subheader using tabs concept in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, ionic2

i am using side menus to navigate to my tabs page.

I am facing an issues with myheader.

How do i get according to the image given here as img1 using tabs concept in ionic2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1Zj.png)

I used the code as

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" primary>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="PROFILE"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="ORDERS"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="PASSWORD"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>


</ion-content>
```

after this code i am getting the out like the below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT00f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the entire code, but think the issue with your code is that you're not including the header in the tabs view. Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MM2biM?p=preview).

Like you can see there, you can achieve that design with this code in your view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      My Account
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-tabs #myTabs primary>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Profile"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Orders"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Password"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```